# Show that $A + A^{T} = 0$ iff $x^{T}Ax = 0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing, quadratic-forms, skew-symmetric-matrices

In the first direction, I know that $A + A^{T} = 0$ implies that all diagonal entries must be zero and each non-diagonal has a negative entry, therefore the entire product $x^{T}Ax = 0$ must be equal to zero. I am just unsure how to write out the proof using summation formulas, etc.

When it comes to proving the second direction, I am not very sure where to start.

Comment: Remember that $(x^T Ax)^T = x^T A^T x$.

Comment: You have forgotten a "$\forall x$"...

Comment: More detailled here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4005068/399263

Comment: On top of @QiaochuYuan reminder, remember that $(x^TAx) = (x^TAx)^T$.